# Pass the resource URI as parameter to a WCF Service Defnition for REST based API(WebInvoke Receiver Methods)

Tags: wcf, rest

I need the base-URI ( or of the resource) which actually triggers this Operation to include it in the response.

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "users/user",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
public bool ReadUserAccount(User user,int TaskID, **string baseURL**)
{
 //do something - Include further subsequent Resource Urls with help of Base URL
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Understood the operation Context of the WCF Framework.

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To
```

reads the URL inside a Service Implementation.